# Material that's only visible if seen through another material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, transparency

I'm trying to replicate the "polarisation" effect - so if you look through a piece of glass that's polarised you can see an image behind that image that normally would be invisible or white as it's been polarised too. So, I want to have a see-through material I can apply to something, so that the thing behind it is only visible if seen through that material. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Will the material possibly be "seen" through other transparent objects you **don't** want to reveal it?  If not, you can test if the Transparent Depth value > 0.

Comment: No, it will be seen through all transparent objects! Can you explain a bit more about testing the Transparent Depth value > 0 ? Where do I do that and how?

Comment: You need render layers.

Comment: @alberto2000 what ShadyPuck answered basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Window:*

[image]

*Material seen through window:*

[image]

*Viewport render showing Suzanne through window:*

[image]

*Viewport render showing invisible Suzanne next to window:*

[image]

What I have is a *Glass BSDF* window, slightly off white in color so to be seen, and with a *1.00 IOR* to be in all rights except one a *Transparent BSDF*. *Glass BSDF*s refract rays like glass refracts light, and I can test for that refraction (called a *Transmission Ray*).

My *Suzanne* has a material (red *Diffuse BSDF*, but can be anything) that is mixed with a pure white (clear) *Transparent BSDF*. The mix *Fac:*, whaddoyouno, just happens to be a *Transmission Ray* :)

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: @alberto2000 Glad to help!