# How can I make an object only visible through certain material

Tags: materials, node-editor, objects, visibility

Hi I am trying to make a certain object only visible through another object with transparent material

lets say object named car and the other object named glass i can see the car if i look through glass but i can't see the car otherwise like looking through another glass or looking to car directly only looking through that glass shows me the car

Basically Masking object's material transparency to another material

Example Image
[image: IMG]

How can i achieve this?
Any help is appreciated

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1Jj-1sMq9g) is what i found with similar effect but only works with grease pencil

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63372/material-thats-only-visible-if-seen-through-another-material) is what i found with similar effect but works for every glass material

I am new here so if i asked my question at the wrong place please correct me

Comment: What do you mean by "like looking through another glass or looking to car directly"? Add some images.

Comment: Added image to post

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your scene and what you need but you could use Light Paths node to make some condition that only one of your glass objects meet. For example you could have two glass planes, but one has another plane in front of it that has a transparent shader:

[image]

You can see the visibility of the orange shader is controlled by Light Paths node's transparency depth output that is 0 when we look through glass, but becomes 1 when there is a plane with transparent shader in front of that glass. You can see what happens if I move the transparent plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i am trying to do is something similar to 1st video i added to post 6 objects inside of a transparent cube and every side of the cube shows only 1 object 
is there any way i can achieve this with light path?

Comment: It's possible to use multiple layers and refraction shaders with IOR of 1 instead of transparency for hiding overlapping objects so they don't change transparency depth, but that gets complicated quite fast.

Answer (score -1):

In such cases mask transparency option is the solution. Anyway, that's Blender Internal.

Comment: Blender Internal is now removed from Blender. It makes sense to take that into account when answering questions.