# Make one material visible only in dense part of volumetric material?

Tags: volumetrics

Sorry if the question is a little confusing

There are some similar questions like
[How can I make an object only visible through certain material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157621/how-can-i-make-an-object-only-visible-through-certain-material) and [Material that's only visible if seen through another material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63372/material-thats-only-visible-if-seen-through-another-material) but they both involve surface materials and I can't seem to translate the answers to volumetric materials.

Suppose I have a volumetric cube, and an object inside it:

[image]

To start the volume is uniformly zero density, and I want the object to not be visible:[image]

But as I increase the density, I want the areas where the dense parts of the volume and the object inside it intersect to be the only place where the object is visible:

[image]

So here the dense volume is red and the star shows up, but where the less dense volume is pink, the object should still not be visible.

I tried playing with the Light Path node but I can't find a light path that I can use to compare the density of the volume for this.